# composite keys in map

Tags: java

Hello I cannot find any info on what I need to do to make two keys seems equal. That is, i need to provide a custom compare method that will be used by map.put() Implementing comparable doesnt help.

For example, this code doesnt work as intended - for the purposes of my program, two keys n and n2 ARE the same.

```
private class N implements Comparable<N> {
        int value;

        int stuff;

        String z;

        @Override
        public int compareTo(N arg0) {
            if (arg0.z.equals(z))
                return 0;
            return 1;
        }

    }

    public void dostuff() {
        HashMap m = new HashMap();

        N n = new N();
        n.z = "1";

        N n2 = new N();
        n2.z = "1";

        m.put(n, "one");
        m.put(n2, "two");

            // will print refs to two instances! - wrong
        Iterator it = m.keySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            System.err.println(it.next());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to override `equals` and `hashCode` - `HashMap` doesn't use `compareTo`, which is meant for *sorting*.

Note that your `compareTo` implementation is already broken, as it's really *only* testing for equality. In particular, `x.compareTo(y)` and `y.compareTo(x)` *both* returning 1 violates the contract of [`compareTo`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28java.lang.Object%29):

> The implementor must ensure sgn(x.compareTo(y)) == -sgn(y.compareTo(x)) for all x and y.

Comment: nice catch, i didnt realise compareTo() is for establishing ORDER amongst objects

Comment: @Saideira: The key is reading the docs: "This interface imposes a total ordering on the objects of each class that implements it." ;)